# IntelliJ to move a class along with conflicted classes to a new package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

When I select `Refactoring > Move` on a Java class and as a result IntelliJ warns that'll cause conflicts for other classes. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to move a class along with any classes that would have conflicts as well?

EDIT: Seems like my original question is unclear so I'm providing an example.

If I have classA that uses ClassB inside. If I move classA to another directory (different maven module), ClassA can no longer access classB. Ideally, IntelliJ would have an option to automatically move classB into the other directory as well.

Comment: hi just click on the class press f6 then select the package to move and press refactor intellij automatically takes care on references

Comment: @M.Sharma I just updated the question with an example . Please have a look.

Comment: In that case it might be an intelliJ bug because after refactoring intellij automatically takes care of import statements

Comment: @M.Sharma It's not the import statements that causes conflicts. ClassB will have compilation errors because it cannot access ClassA that is now in another directory/module.

Comment: Boss just which ever class is giving you the compiler error for import just keep the cursor over there and press `ALT+ENTER` and from the pop-up menu add the import statement of the module path

Comment: The import is not the problem. The problem can be solved by moving ClassB as well into this new module. But this is a recursive problem, because classes that ClassB may use will also have to be moved. I want a way for IntelliJ to do this automatically.

Comment: You dint get me.When you call classA from moduleA in classB of ModuleB it shows you some red line right just keep the cursor over it press ALT+ENTER and select the classA module package from the menu thats it

Comment: Is there a way to get IntelliJ to do this automatically? My example was trivial with two classes. ClassA could be using 10 classes and those classes could be calling other classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to move a class(you can do Refactoring > Move or hit F6 or simply drag&drop) Intellij gives some some options like:

`Search in comments and strings`

`Search for text occurrences`

`Search for references` etc..

If you select all these Intellij will handle your dependencies. So you don't have to worry about them.

Check also [Move Class Dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/move-class-dialog.html)

Comment: I do not see the "Search for reference" option in IDEA 13. [Screenshot](http://oi61.tinypic.com/qpgs1u.jpg)

Comment: Yes you are right. The documentation refers that this option is available only for Move File or Move Package refactorings. But anyway if you check the two checkboxes you are going to be fine.

Comment: Seems like my original question is unclear since so I'm providing an example. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access modifiers of all classes that you try to move.

Maybe you've used 'package-private'(default) modifier and then, when you move these classes to another package, other classes lose access to them.

Comment: I understand why the classes result in conflict. The question is for a way to move those classes along to the new package.